# I have to determine if the system is linear, time-invariant, and/or causal

Tags: signal, math

Here is my problem:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 5\frac{dy}{dt} + 8y(t) = \frac{dx}{dt} + 3x(t)$$

I have to prove if this system is homogeneous and additive in order for the function to be linear, but can I prove that? It says the output should be as the input, and again how can I solve the above problem? For example, \$x(t)\$ must equal \$y(t)\$ how can I implement that rule into the function?

Comment: If \$x(t)=y(t)\$ you'll probably want to fill in \$x(t)\$ for \$y(t)\$ or the other way around, \$y(t)\$ for \$x(t)\$.

Comment: good idea, let me try that, thanks so it should looks like this (d^2*dx/dt+3x(t))/dt +5(dx/dt+3x(t)/dt +8y(dx/dt+3x(t))?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean \$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\$ in that first term?

Comment: This might be a better fit over at the signal processing stackexchange dsp.SE.

Comment: Dilip you are right however, i do know how to edit the question

Comment: @DrFriedParts sorry, that was my mistake. My edit was wrong.

Comment: This question hasn’t been answered, mainly due to the fact the question wasn’t asked clearly. For example x(t) = y(t) makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide some hints on how to do this (if it's not clear to you after this, please say so and I'll try to clarify):

First let's see what the linearity is all about: as it's noted in the question, you should prove homogeneity and additivity and we can do that directly from the properties of differentials.

Let's assume that first and second derivatives of y exist. Additivity tells us that if for input \$y_1\$, we get output \$x_1\$ and for input \$y_2\$, we get output \$x_2\$, then for input \$(y_1+y_2)\$, we should get output \$(x_1+x_2)\$. So we have

\$\frac{d^2y_1(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{dy_1(t)}{dt} + 8y_1(t) = \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt} + 3x_1(t)\$

\$\frac{d^2y_2(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{dy_2(t)}{dt} + 8y_2(t) = \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt} + 3x_2(t)\$

Now if we remember that derivative of a sum is sum of derivatives, we can write following:

$$\frac{d^2 (y_1+y_2)(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{d(y_1+dy_2)(t)}{dt} + 8(y_1+y_2)(t)= \\ = \frac{d^2y_1(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{dy_1(t)}{dt} + 8y_1(t) + \frac{d^2y_2(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{dy_2(t)}{dt} + 8y_2(t) $$

So we got the sum of the first and second equations as the result of the third. It hsould be obvious now what happens with the output.

As for the homogeneity, we can remember what happens when we take a derivative of a variable multiplied by constant:

\$ \frac{d^2cy_1(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{dcy_1(t)}{dt} + 8cy_1(t)=c\frac{d^2y_1(t)}{dt^2}+ 5c\frac{dy_1(t)}{dt} + 8cy_1(t)=c\left(\frac{d^2 (y_1)(t)}{dt^2}+ 5\frac{d(y_1)(t)}{dt} + 8(y_1)(t)\right)\$

Next we have time invariance: A system which for input \$y(t)\$ generates output \$x(t)\$ for input \$y(t-t_0)\$ generates output \$x(t-t_0)\$ is called time-invariant. To test this, simply at all locations where you have \$y(t)\$ and \$x(t)\$, you replace them with \$y(t-t_0)\$ and \$x(t-t_0)\$. Then take a look at the system. If all times are in the \$t-t_0\$ format, then the system is time-invariant. If you find a lone t somewhere, then it's not time-invariant.

Finally we have causality. Property of causality simply states that if system's output is \$x(t)\$ at moment \$t=t_0\$, then it's output can only depend on inputs \$y(t)\$ for \$t \leq t_0\$. More simply, the system is causal if it can work without being able to foretell the future\$^1\$. To test this, simply put a number instead of t. Once you do all time calculations, if you at any point in the result get a number which is greater than your t number, the system is not causal.

\$^1\$ At first it may look strange to see a non-causal system, since it needs to know future in order to see what's happening now, but if you're doing batch processing on a set of data, then you already have future data available, so this works out fine.

Comment: AndreajaKo this help so much thanks, can you clarify linearity one more time, what i am understand it is linearity because of the constant?

Comment: @carlos Take a look one more time carefully. Linearity is due to both homogeneity and additivity, as you wrote in the question. If you look up the definition of homogeneity, you'll see that it means that if we multiply input by a constant, output also gets multiplied by that same constant. So, a part of linearity is due to the constant. If the output somehow changed by a value which is different that that same constant which we used to multiply the input, then the system wouldn't be linear.

Comment: @carlos Also sorry, I wrote in my answer linearity at one point, but I meant homogeneity. It's fixed now.

Comment: thanks, I understand now, I have being working on this for awhile and finally you made all clear, thanks

Comment: @carlos I'm happy to help.

Comment: I am going to try another example for practice, is it ok to post it here so you can give me some advise? thanks again

Comment: @carlos *I* don't have any problems with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8481/discussion-between-carlos-and-andrejako)

Comment: @AndrejaKo Your statements are completely backwards. In the differential equation given to the OP, the _output_ is \$y(t)\$ and the input is \$x(t)\$. Also, in testing for homoegeneity etc, you need to look at the RHS as well. For example, \$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+a\frac{dy}{dt}+by(t)=x(t)\$ describes a linear system but \$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+a\frac{dy}{dt}+by(t)=x^2(t)\$ does not.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate As strange as it may sound, OP firmly claimed that in fact y(t) is input and x(t) is output. I was also trying not to do his homework for him, but you are right that I should have been more explicit about the right side of the equation.

Comment: @AndrejaKo The OP also claimed that " For example, \$x(t)\$ must equal \$y(t)\$ how can I implement that rule into the function?" indicating that he either really didn't understand what was being asked, or there is a problem with translation into English if the OP was asked the question in a different language.

Comment: I don’t understand the statement “It hsould be obvious now what happens with the output.”  Plus the left hand sides of the equations are completely missing. Also x is the input not y

Answer (score 1):

The input to this system is denoted by \$x(t)\$ and its output by \$y(t)\$.

- To prove that the system is *homogeneous*, what you need to show is
  that

  > if input \$x(t)\$ produces output \$y(t)\$,
  >   then the output produced by input \$\alpha\cdot x(t)\$ is \$\alpha\cdot y(t)\$.

  Here, \$\alpha\$ is an arbitrarily chosen real number, that is, the highlighted
  statement must hold regardless of the value of \$\alpha\$.  Similarly,
  the requirement must be satisfied regardless of the choice of input \$x(t)\$.
  In other words, finding one pair of input and output signals \$x(t)\$ and \$y(t)\$ 
  and one real number \$\alpha\$ for which the highlighted statement is true
  is not sufficient; it has to hold for *all* such choices.
- To prove that the system is additive, what you need to show is that

  > if inputs \$x_1(t)\$ and \$x_2(t)\$ produce outputs \$y_1(t)\$
  >   and \$y_2(t)\$ respectively, 
  >   then the output produced by input \$x_1(t)+x_2(t)\$ is 
  >   \$y_1(t)+y_2(t)\$.

  Once again, cherry-picking is not allowed; the statement has to hold
  for all choices of input signals and corresponding output signals.

It is not too hard to verify that your system is both homogeneous
and additive.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, it just gives the standard definitions from textbooks.

Comment: @rhody Thanks for the downvote. On all the SE forums that I usually frequent, it is standard practice to not give full answers to what are obviously homework questions. Here the OP very clearly had no clue as to _what_ needed to be done to even approach the problem. Now that ten years have passed and the homework deadline is presumably long past, I look forward to reading your own full answer to the question that hopefully dots all i's and crosses all t's.

Comment: I assumed you knew the answer. Would be great if you could provide it.

Comment: The "answer" is right there in the last line of my post. If you mean the detailed working out of _how_ the proof is actually written down., sorry: work it out for yourself. It is presumably your current homework.